# My website URL with www shows the correct content but shows the Apache2 Ubuntu Default page without www. How do I correct this?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, flask

I followed the [How To Deploy a Flask Application on an Ubuntu VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps)
 and [How To Install the Apache Web Server on Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-20-04#step-5-%E2%80%94-setting-up-virtual-hosts-(recommended))
from Digital Ocean where my hosting is. I have two type A DNS records set up where the hostname is my URL with www and my URL without it, that direct to the value of my public IP.

I can change which address shows the correct information by changing ServerName to either my public IP, my website with www, or my website without www. How can I make it so that [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) and mywebsite.com both show correctly? A redirect surely can't be the right answer?

Here is the conf file: /etc/apache2/sites-available/FlaskApp.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName www.mywebsite.com
                ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried adding a permanent redirect it didn't work.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName www.mywebsite.com
                Redirect permanent / http://mywebsite.com/
                ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else with this problem I found a solution by adding a server alias:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName www.mywebsite.com
            ServerAlias mywebsite.com
            ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
            <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
            <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```